# Why might MultiBit not show a transaction that was sent to me?

Tags: blockchain, money, import, multibit

So i recently bought a bitcoin from a vendor , and i had it sent to my Address in multibit.

Now the problem is , the money isn't there and i'm not sure what to do.

He told me to get bitcoin (program) and now it's starting to download a chain. Currently it's at 95000.

I'm not sure what to do exactly , as i'm worried i may have lost my funds.

What can i do at this point? Do i wait till the Blockchain is finished or should i import my wallet from Multibit to Bitcoin?

Thanks guys!

-D

Comment: PS. If you're worried that the merchant scammed you, you can put your bitcoin address into [this website](http://blockexplorer.com/) and it will tell you how much your address really holds.

Comment: You can ask the vendor for the transaction id of the transaction they sent you. Look it up on http://blockchain.info to check it exists and is sending bitcoin to your receiving address. Look at the date of the transaction. Go into MultiBit, select your wallet and do a 'Tools | Reset blockchain and transactions' and reset from the day before the transaction. Once it has resynced to the network you should see it in MultiBit.

Comment: @jim618 that would probably be the accepted answer (to the revised question title) if you were to add it as one.

Comment: Good job marking it as a duplicate of "before properly synced" when the asker didn't mention that symptom. Heck, the "duplicate" doesn't even mention MultiBit! Over-zealous duplicate marking is annoying.

Comment: Actual answer: because of a bug in MultiBit. You need to "Reset Blockchain and Transactions" for the transaction to appear.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask the vendor for the transaction id of the transaction where they sent the bitcoin to you. Look it up on https://blockchain.info to check it exists and is sending bitcoin to your receiving address correctly. Look at the date of the transaction. Go into MultiBit, select your wallet and choose the menu option 'Tools | Reset blockchain and transactions'. Reset from the day before the transaction. Once it has resynced to the network you should see it in MultiBit.